# How can LastLoginDate be greater than SystemModstamp?

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to replicate the Salesforce data in our database, using their REST API. There is [a general guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/data_replication_steps.htm) on how to do this. But on [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335322&type=1) they're saying that the get updated service would use the `SystemModStamp` field. I want to query the record, so a `SELECT * FROM sfObject WHERE SystemModStamp > value of my last stored SystemModStamp` command would be more suitable.

The strange thing is that it seems like the `SystemModStamp` is not updated each time when another field is updated. Is that possible? There is a User record, where the `SystemModStamp` remained the same (2022-01-25 21:30), but the `LastLoginDate` got updated (yesterday it was 2022-01-25 21:50, but this morning it was 2022-01-26 05:50, now it's 2022-01-26 15:20). Well if the user logged in thus the `LastLoginDate` is changed, why didn't the `SystemModStamp` changed too? This way my filter won't return the new last login timestamp. Nor the get update service if called with start = 2022-01-25 21:31.

Surely I would be able to filter for `LastLoginDate` too. But is that enough? Why is there `SystemModStamp` (or if not available,  `LastModifiedDate`/`CreatedDate`) if it doesn't tell when was the record last changed? If I add all date fields to the filter, will I always get all changed records?

Answer (score 0):

Login doesn't update the User record (unless you have code running on login like SSO JIT handler or login flows...) so systemmodstamp stays the same. LastLoginDate, Last password reset, # failed login attempts are weird special fields. From what I remember sysadmins can see it but regular users can't.

LastLogin is based on related LoginHistory table. Resetting user's password doesn't count as an update either. Neither does Freeze/Unfreeze (check UserLogin table)

If you need to sync everything I'd consider syncing users without any WHERE clause